# How do I center 4 uibuttons with equal distance from each other?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, autolayout, constraints

I have 4 uibuttons. Each button MUST be 100x100. I want to center the 4 of them in the center of my screen (horizontally), but put them down vertically. I have no idea where to start, but i've heard stackviews might work? Not sure. I tried using basic constraints, but i was unable to get them to work.

here is what im trying to get:
[image]

Comment: Do you plan on doing this programmatically or with StoryBoard?

Comment: What is your requirement ? Pls provide relevant details. What constraints did you use ? If you are only targeting iOS 9 and above, you should use stack views!

Comment: please check my answer.

Comment: ios8, preferably with storyboard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Step 1 :-** take 4 button in your Storyboard. Button1 , Button2 , Button 3 ,        Button4

**Step 2 :-** Give Fixed Height and width to All buttons .

[image]

**Step 3 :-** All 2 - 2 button's pair in 2 stackview.

[image]

**Step 4 :-** Set UIStackview Property for both .

```
      Distribution -> Fill Equally
           Spacing -> 5 (as per your requirement)
```

[image]

---

[image]

**Step 5 :-** Add both Stackview in one Stackview

[image]

**Step 6 :-** Set `Distribution = Fill equally Spacing =5` in main stackview (set According to your requirement)

[image]

**Step 7 :-** Now set Constrain to main stackview

```
      center Horizontally in container

      center vertically in container

        and select Update Frame.
```

[image]

**Step 8 :-** It's time for Output for All device .

[image]

I hope it will be helpful for you.

Comment: trying it now, thanks for the nicely detailed explanation!

Comment: @RonakShah welcome. if you face any difficulty feel free and ask me .

Comment: Sorry for the late acceptance, didn't get a chance, THANK YOU SO MUCH :D

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways, look one:

Idea:

1. First put all buttons equals width and height constraint, and to one of the button add constraints to width and height 100.
2. For each button center X/Y with respect to his parent.
   Constraint: Align Center X, Align Center Y
3. Add offset to the constant (In interface builder):

   - Top Left button: Offset X of -60, Y of -60
   - Top Right button: Offset X of 60, Y of -60
   - Bottom Left Button: Offset X of -60, Y of 60
   - Bottom Right Button: Offset X of 60, Y of 60.

Quick Example (I did the constraint in IB):
https://github.com/Abreu0101/ButtonLayout

========

Another option that you have is using transparent view's between the buttons, and center this view's (transparent), and add constraint to the buttons base on these views (Sometimes that's I tricky that I used, but all depends on what you need).

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this without using UIStackView (if you need this to be work on < iOS 9)[image]