# Constraints not working

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-autolayout

I am not sure why but I have having so much trouble with constrains and auto layout. I have the below view and I want to make it display as is shown but every single approach I take to get seems to be incorrect.

I have been following this tutorial online [Auto Layout Tutorial in iOS](https://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2) and I am rather trying to describe my constraints. Following this technique this is what I have:

**Description of my constraints.**

Label:

- Centered in the view
- 51 from the top

All images:

- Must have equal height and equal width.
- Are separated from the left and right by a 0 gutter.
- All inner gutters separating the images are 12.

I have also included my storyboard.
[storyboard link](http://speedy.sh/46wr6/Main.storyboard)

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I center 4 uibuttons with equal distance from each other?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37331644/how-do-i-center-4-uibuttons-with-equal-distance-from-each-other)

Comment: share your output screen shot and original screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

for this you just declare height and width of the first imageview with respect ViewController use equal heights and equal widths and then change in the multiplier default it will be 1 adjust to your size then for the remaining imageviews you just give equal widths and equal heights of the first imageview.

Answer (score 0):

If you want keep height and width constant , don't pin it, just use horizontal centre constraint. Pin it up using auto layout , hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You are set image height and set image bottom constraint and does not set label height that you are many choice

- Set your label height because you run iPhone 4 or 4s that your label doesn't display.
- remove your image bottom constraint because you are set fix image height.
- you image doesn't fix height that remove your set image height and all image select and set equal height constraint (all image height same).

Answer (score 0):

Better You should move that four image views into a uiview(childView) .Make sure that 4 image views are the subviews of UIView.

-Add equal width and hight constraint to SuperView from the childView.
- Add multiplier value for the EqualHight and Equal Width constraints by selecting both constraints on storyboard(like 1:2.1,1:2.2).it may keep the same distance in all orientation

- Add Y position and X position by trailing space and leading space, centre vertical in container.
- Then Select the 4 uiimageviews and make sure they have same width and hight,after that
- select 4 image views then click the pin button and check the equal width and equal hight.
- Add leading ,top and trailing space for image1
- [1,2]

  [3,4]
- add trailing and top space for image 2
- add leading ,top and bottom space for image 3
- add trailing ,top and bottom space for image 4,